# Remove ctrl character except tab

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

I have a tab delimited file which has many junk cntrl characters. I want to remove the control characters except tab (which is ^I). Hence I would need a POSIX Regex which would Identify control characters excluding Tab characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
tr -Cd '[:print:]\n\t' < file
```

This will only print printable characters, newlines and `\t` instances.

Comment: @devnull: Re `-C` vs. `-c`: I've never understood the _conceptual_ difference between `-C` and `-c` - in _practice_, they seem to do the same. GNU `tr`s command-line help, for instance, lists them simply as synonyms. The POSIX spec (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/utilities/tr.html) distinguishes between _characters_ (`-C`) and _values (`-c`), but doesn't explain what 'values' are. Can you explain the difference?

Comment: Just that `-c` seems more standard.  On BSD, `-C` would give an error.

Comment: @devnull: After some digging (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.unix.shell/nicHqKG4Tlo) I conclude: `-C` is _locale-aware_ (support for multi-byte chars.) and thus preferable; `-c`, by contrast, operates on _bytes_. `-C` has been part of POSIX since POSIX:2001 (SUSv3). When you say BSD, I assume you mean BSD-_like_ platforms; both FreeBSD and OSX _do_ support `-C` - are you aware of any that do not?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `tr`:

```
tr -d '\000-\010\013-\037' < inputfile
```

Comment: `\008` would be better as `\010`

Comment: 8 isn't an octal digit! 010 *is* decimal 8.

Comment: +1 for showing how to use ranges with octal-encoded characters.